# MASM accessing and adding to the first element of an array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am converting string user input to integers and storing said integers in an array. I can print the integers before they have been added and from the array inside my ReadVal procedure and the numbers match up with the keyboard input.

However, when I try to print the first element of the array in main, I get a very different number. The 2nd, 3rd and 4th print accurately. When I store integers beginning with the second element I have no problem and everything gets stored correctly. What would change the first element after the procedure has completed?

How I print the first element in main:

```
mov     esi, OFFSET array
mov     eax, [esi]
call    WriteDec

Printing the second:
mov     esi, OFFSET array
mov     eax, [esi + 4]
call    WriteDec
```

In case it helps, here is my code for reading integers in string and converting them to numbers:

```
  readVal PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     edi, [ebp + 24]     ; @array

    getString:
        xor     edx, edx
        mov     eax, edi ; Address of current element in array
        sub     eax, [ebp + 24] ; subtract the starting address from the current
        cmp     eax, 40 ; If 10 DWORDS have been added to the array, jump to finish
        je      readValFinish   

        mGetString [ebp + 8] ; store value in @dString

        ; Convert the string to numeric value
        mov     esi, [ebp + 8] ; @dString
        mov     ecx, eax         ; length of the string

        ;Set X to 0
        mov     ebx, 0
        cld             ; Set direction to forward
    convertNext:
        lodsb       ; Gets the char in AL
        cmp     al, 48
        jl      outOfRange
        cmp     al, 57
        jg      outOfRange
        jmp     goodChar

    outOfRange:
        mov     edx, [ebp + 16]
        call    WriteString
        call    Crlf
        ;mov        eax, 0   ;Signals they guessed an invalid number
        jmp     getString

    ; If it's a valid character, add it to the total    
    goodChar:
        ; subtract 48
        sub     al, 48
        push        eax
        ; multiply x by 10
        mov     eax, ebx
        ;call   WriteDec
        mov     ebx, 10
        mul     ebx
        mov     ebx, eax ; x back in ebx
        pop     eax    
        add     ebx, eax 

    loop    convertNext
    call    Crlf

    ; If valid, add numeric value (EBX) to an array
    mov     eax, ebx
    call    WriteDec

    mov     [edi], eax

    mov     eax, [edi]
    call    WriteDec

;   xor     eax, eax
;   mov     eax, [edi]
;   call    WriteDec

    add     edi, 4      ;Move to the next position

    jmp     getString

readValFinish:
    pop     ebp
    ret     20  ; 5 pushed on the stack

readVal ENDP
```

Comment: can you specify the contents of the array?

Comment: Sure. The array is filled with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't look like overwriting the array.

If the first element of array is already modified after returning from `readVal`, then it's probably problem in one of `mGetString`, `WriteDec`, `WriteString`, `Crlf`, or whichever are called.

If the first element is OK after `readVal`, keep printing it between that point and main, to see after which part it gets modified. Or **use debugger**.

Basically **use the debugger anyway and often**. It's not very easy to write valid assembler code on the first try, rigorously step-by-single-instruction each routine is quite often only way to spot any weak spots, or mistakes.

I had once an data optimization routine, which was running under DOS fine, and under windows twice as fast ... after debugging I found out: the test checking if the data have to be optimized was comparing the offset of one label instead of value in memory. Thus under DOS it was running every time (code was loaded to some low address space), under windows it was never run (code loaded at some virtual 0x8... address). I was unable to spot that one without debugger (and I got hint about it only thanks to profiling the performance).